# How to use Google's web cache to view a page

Tags: google-search, cached-webpages

I have this Google webcache link of Forbes.com:

> http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YITURJmnFeUJ:www.forbes.com/celebrities2004/LIR4XKR.html%3FpassListId%3D53%26passYear%3D2004%26passListType%3DPerson%26uniqueId%3D4XKR%26datatype%3DPerson+&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Is there any way I can go to the next or previous person on that list using Google's web cache?

The 'next' and 'previous' links are in the page I linked.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work anymore. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:YITURJmnFeUJ:www.forbes.com/celebrities2004/LIR4XKR.html%3FpassListId%3D53%26passYear%3D2004%26passListType%3DPerson%26uniqueId%3D4XKR%26datatype%3DPerson+&cd=5&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us says 404 error.

Comment: For easier access you can use this: https://www.cachedview.me

Answer (score 57):

You can access the cached version for any page that has been saved by Google with this:

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://example.com/
```

Change http://example.com/ to any URL. You can also create a custom search engine to go to cached versions automatically by adding a keyword before the current URL address.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [The Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php) to view those pages. Just right click on the [Next](http://www.forbes.com/finance/lists/53/2004/LIR.jhtml?passListId=53&passYear=2004&passListType=Person&uniqueId=PCS9&datatype=Person) and [Previous](http://www.forbes.com/finance/lists/53/2004/LIR.jhtml?passListId=53&passYear=2004&passListType=Person&uniqueId=Y6W8&datatype=Person), and copy their link locations. Then paste these locations into [The Wayback Machine](http://archive.org/web/web.php)'s search bar and hit enter. For example, pasting the link of `Previous` takes you back to [the older version](http://web.archive.org/web/20090527154217/http://www.forbes.com/celebrities2004/LIRY6W8.html?passListId=53&passYear=2004&passListType=Person&uniqueId=Y6W8&datatype=Person) of the page dated May 27, 2009, which lists Bruce Springsteen.

[image]

Comment: This is problematic for sites with robots.txt that disables it.